# AWS Lambda function to start "Simple Workflow(SWF)" Execution in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, timeout, amazon-swf

Is it possible to start a AWS-SWF workflow from a Lambda function registered in AWS?

I wrote a POC in Java using "Flow Framework" to start a workflow from Lambda, triggered by S3 insertion. But the lambda function, while trying to talk to SWF through REST, is giving a timeout.

Do I need to do any extra configuration for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to start a swf workflow from a lambda function. Only thing is that the lambda function should have internet access.

By default lambda functions have internet access if they are not created inside a VPC. If you create it inside a VPC you have to configure internet access via a NAT. Check the "Internet Access for Lambda Functions" section in link below for more details.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html